# How to best render react components dynamically from data model

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create texteditor with React.JS that works a bit like Sir Trevor(https://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/example.html). So you basically have blocks of different types of content that you order, edit and embed.

I have a JSON data set from the backend that looks like this.

```js
var content = [
    {"tag": "p", "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."},
    {"tag": "Youtube", "content": "dQw4w9WgXcQ"},
    {"tag": "ul", "content": [
        {"tag": "li", "content": "Rick"},
        {"tag": "li", "content": "Astley"},
    ]},
    {"tag": "TagCloud", "content": ["news","opinon","papers"]}
];
```

Youtube and TagCloud are React classes. I render the code like this:

```
var ArticleContent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var elments = this.props.content;
    var reactElements = []
    for (var elementIndex in elments) {
      if (elments.hasOwnProperty(elementIndex)) {
        var tagname = elments[elementIndex].tag;
        var content = elments[elementIndex].content;
        console.log(tagname.toString());
        if(!/(div|p|li)/.test(tagname))
          tagname = React.createFactory(tagname)
        reactElements.push(React.createElement(tagname, null, content));
      }
    }

    return (
      React.createElement('div', {className: 'articleContent'},
        reactElements
      )
    );
  }
});
React.render(
  <ArticleContent content={content}></ArticleContent>
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Now my whish is to render normal html tags with just createElement, but for those matching a defined React component Class, I want to render using the components render method.

As far as I understand this is not possible because `createElement` only accepts proper React objects or strings of html tags. Help please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`React.createElement`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement) accepts tag names as strings:

> Create and return a new ReactElement of the given type. The type argument can be either an html tag name string (eg. 'div', 'span', etc), or a `ReactClass` (created via `React.createClass`).

Look at your own code example :)

```
React.createElement('div', {className: 'articleContent'},
  reactElements
)
```

You could have a lookup for custom component names to the corresponding `ReactClass` and assume everything else is a regular HTML tag.